# Loop through all "widgets"/elements in a Activity

Tags: java, android, for-loop, widget

I started my own android app a few days ago since I needed a mobile application to store a bunch of data I collect in the hospital.

I'm pretty new to Java and android environment, although it seems easy to understand and very similar to C++.

Anyway, my application has a bunch of "EditText" and radio buttons and my question is:

How can I iterate through all those widgets (EditTexts and radio buttons)?

In .NET you could do a "for each element in container " loop but I can't seem to find a way to do this in Java/android environment.

Note: I don't know how many "widgets" exist in the activity, since some are created dinamicaly, others are hardcoded and some others show if some user preferences are set

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++)
  rootView.getChildAt(i)
```

Note that this will return View-s, you will have to check at runtime exactly what type of View you are currently looking at

Comment: Interesting. But the start point was an activity. So your demo is missing the step from activity to rootView ;-) — I probably can figure it out myself but it would have been nice.

Answer (score 1):

It works.

Regarding the View type (ie Spinner, radioButton, EditText, etc) we can tag each type we want to parse in the Layout XML file and then add a conditional, ie:

```
   if (Widget_Tag != null){   

      View Current_Widget = (View) rootView.getChildAt(i);          

      String Widget_Tag = (String) Current_Widget.getTag();

      if (Widget_Tag.equals("MyEdiText")) {

        //do something

      }
   }
```

the if (Widget_Tag != null){ is to prevent NullPointReferences. You can also doi it with a Try / Catch.

Comment: Like I said to apps: where is `rootView` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

ViewGroup Current_Widget = (ViewGroup)l.getRootView();

for (int i = 0; i < Current_Widget.getChildCount(); i++)
    Current_Widget.getChildAt(i);
```